# Error code 2500 Facebook login on Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, swift3

I am trying to integrate the Facebook login into iOS 10 app with swift 3.0.
i getting error code 2500 as shown below after setup the FacebookSDK into the app:

**error code on console:**

```
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 2500;
        "fbtrace_id" = FpAkfsaBAFc;
        message = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}})
```

**loginButton function on loginViewController:**

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

    fetchProfile()
    print("@@@@Completed Login@@@@")

}
```

**Fetch Facebook Profile function on loginVC:**

```
func fetchProfile() {


    let parameters = ["fields": "email, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large)"]

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters).start(completionHandler: { (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in

        if requestError != nil {
            print(requestError)
            print("There are some error during getting the request from fb")
            return
        }

        self.email = (user?["email"] as? String)!
        self.firstName = (user?["first_name"] as? String)!
        self.lastName = (user?["last_name"] as? String)!

        self.nameLabel.text = "\(self.firstName) \(self.lastName)"
        print("My fbname is " + self.firstName)
        print(self.lastName)

        var pictureUrl = ""

        if let picture = user?["picture"] as? NSDictionary, let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary, let url = data["url"] as? String {
            pictureUrl = url
            print(pictureUrl)
        }

    })
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    return true
}



func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

Had search for similar question on stack overflow, but not working on swift 3.0, Would be appreciated if anyone could advise on this issue, thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had solved the issue as the keychain access has been disabled by default in iOS10  , Enable the **KeyChain Sharing** under **Capabilities** and Facebook login is working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you´re missing the access_token. Make a control before you make a request and check if access_token is nil, then request for a new one. After that you should be able to make your requests.